# Trying to get property of non-object - laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relationship

I am using Laravel eloquent relationship, when i use

```
    {{$subject->cat}}
```

i receive a json response like below

```
    {"id":13,"name":"Fsc","created_at":"2017-10-23 00:00:00","updated_at":"2017-10-23 00:00:00"}
```

as i have 2nd object "name" here i tried

```
    {{$subject->cat->name}}
```

but got error

```
    Trying to get property of non-object
```

while i am using same approach for other table and copied same method here but getting error.

See my Blade file code, i am calling object inside foreach loop

```
      @foreach ($subjects as $subject)
                    <tr>
                      <td width="8%">{{$subject->id}}</td>
                      <td width="22%">{{$subject->subject}} </td>
                      <td width="22%">{{$subject->cat->name}}</td>
                        <!-- <a class="btn btn-success btn-sm" href="{{route('subjects.show', $subject->id)}}"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i></a> |  -->
                        <a href="{{route('subjects.edit', $subject->id)}}" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></a> |
                          {!! Form::open(['route' => ['subjects.destroy', $subject->id], 'method' => 'DELETE', 'class' => 'delete-form']) !!}
                          {{ Form::button('<i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i>', ['class' => 'btn btn-danger btn-sm pull-left', 'type' => 'submit']) }}
                          {!! Form::close() !!}
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                    @endforeach
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `json_decode` like:

```
$var = json_decode($subject, true);
```

Then you can use:

```
{{$subject->cat->name}}
```

See more [here!](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

Hope this helps you!

Comment: amazing this is that i used same approach for other relationship as laravel allow this magic. $subject is coming after foreach loop. can you help me with laravel method?

Comment: The `json_decode` is only you need to use! Try now, i updated my answer!

Comment: sorry no success

Comment: `json_decode` converts into a PHP variable! How you tried?

Comment: You can also do like: `dd(json_decode($subject->cat, true));` This gives you `{"id":13,"name":"Fsc","created_at":"2017-10-23 00:00:00","updated_at":"2017-10-23 00:00:00"}`

Comment: i have same output without json because of laravel eloquent relationship

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157364/discussion-between-rj-syed-hassan-raza-and-hiren-gohel).

Comment: Sorry, there is no chat allow in my office! You can post your comments here!

Comment: your way is fine but issue is that i made same relationship for my lesson table and used same method that i shown in my post and it was successful while i copied method here but failed :( we can get data without json i read everywhere. any ways thanks for you help

Comment: i am following this approach
 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xIBST5vVq84&list=PLfdtiltiRHWEb-tzSN99Zy-39Y1tKl5DB

Comment: @RjSyedHassanRaza Ok, please give upvote to my answer if you thank me! I will max try to fix your problem.

Comment: Thank you man! You can also upvote it to click on up arrow! :)

Answer (score 2):

### First Use [json_decode($json);](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

Takes a JSON encoded string and converts it into a PHP variable.

Then

```
Use {{$subject->cat}}
```

Comment: i am looking for laravel eloquent approach

Answer (score 1):

Try this

`$cat = json_decode($subject->cat); // returns object
{{ $cat['name'] }}`

or

`$cat = json_decode($subject->cat, true); // returns array
{{ $cat['name'] }}`

Comment: for first method getting error. 
(1/1) FatalErrorException
Call to a member function toArray() on null

for 2nd methor getting error like my question title. 

but last methor is working. but as my readings we can get result without json 

i was using this approach 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xIBST5vVq84&list=PLfdtiltiRHWEb-tzSN99Zy-39Y1tKl5DB

Answer (score 1):

You need to decode your json and then use like this:

```
$result = json_decode ($subject->cat);
echo $result->name;
```

Use your variable name in place of `$result`

For insight here is [pastebin demo](https://paste.laravel.io/5c7480d3-4f0d-466d-9cb1-4d8368fde96b)

Comment: Laravel blade file not accepting this variable i tried this solution already but getting error Undefined variable: result (View: E:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\lea\resources\views\admin\subjects\index.blade.php)

Comment: change result variable with the variable you are passing to blade :)

Comment: i got answer from you and all above examples but problem is i got result before without json decode, why now here :(

Comment: i was following this approach 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xIBST5vVq84&list=PLfdtiltiRHWEb-tzSN99Zy-39Y1tKl5DB